# I need to Authenticate my users with their Windows Credentials at a Intranet Site

Tags: php, windows, ldap

Is there any possible way to pass Windows-/ username and password to a PHP Script so it can perform a LDAP Authentication in order to create SSO for my Intranet users.

My Authentication works well atm if the user enters his credentials into a Form but i want to take it a step further and create a SSO.

So what i want to achieve is that the username and the Password of Windows are inside of php variables that i can then use to authenticate via php-ldap.

I'm in total control over the Clients atm and will add an exception for those who are accessing in other ways.

Would be nice if you could lead me the way to a Solution.

Thanks in Expanse

Greetings Oswin

Comment: you might be able to query WMI to find those details (`Win32_LogonSession` or `Win32_UserAccount`)?

Comment: If you're running PHP on Windows you can just configure IIS to use Windows Authentication. The exact scenario isn't really clear though, nor what you mean by SSO in this context - it's not really a concept you use/need when talking about Windows/Kerberos authentication. If a specific site uses Windows auth then you don't need to a log a user into it manually, they will just be authenticated by the site when they visit it (assuming they're browsing from a machine which is joined to the relevant domain). We need a lot more clarity on your precise architecture before we can really help.

Comment: *"username and the Password of Windows are inside of php variables"* - Nothing good will come of this.